# orientdb load graph csv of nodes and edges

Tags: csv, graph, import, etl, orientdb

I'm a newbie in Orientdb .
I have a csv file which has both the nodes and the edge and I need to create a graph out of that csv file . 
**csv file**

```
"p1","p2","score"
"LGG_00001","LGG_01682",282
"LGG_00001",".LGG_01831",183
"LGG_00001","LGG_01491",238
```

The edge is IsActingWith which had the score attribute

```
{
"source": {
    "file": {
        "path": "C:/Users/sams/Desktop/OrientDB2/lac2.csv"
    }
},
"extractor": {
    "csv": {}
},
"transformers": [
    {
        "vertex": {
            "class": "lac2"
        }
    },
    {
        "vertex": {
            "class": "lac2"
        }
    },

    {
        "edge":
        {
                "class": "IsActingWith",
                "joinFieldName": "score_p",
                "lookup": "acore",
                "direction": "out"
        }
    }

],
"loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "plocal:C:/Users/sams/Desktop/OrientDB2/database/proj",
        "dbType": "graph",
        "dbAutoCreate": true,
        "classes": [
            {
                "name": "lac2",
                "extends": "V"
            },
            {
                "name": "lac2",
                "extends": "V"
            },
            {
                "name": "IsActingWith",
                "extends": "E"
            },

        ]

    }
}
}
```

That is what I tried but it does not seem logic to me. 
The final result I'm looking for is to have a graaph made of `p1->ACTINGWITH-> p2` and `ACTINGWITH` has score of the score attribute

Comment: What version are you using? What output are you getting?

Comment: Hi, if what you need is creating only an edge class and a vertex class then your code is already correct, otherwise, do you want to connect between single vertex class properties or having two different vertex classes and connect them together? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi Yes I need to connect the 2 vertexes made of p1 and p2 field and the relationship (ACTING WITH) has as a property  the score

Comment: so p1 and p2 has to be 2 vertices of same class `lac2`, right?

Comment: @IvanMainetti yes

Comment: @IvanMainetti yes p1 , p2 refering to the same class and s is a property of the edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe there's a better solution but this works.
My plan is to use 3 different etl scripts: first and second for inserting the vertices and the third for the edges. Of course you'll need to execute them in order.

**vertex_import_p1.json**

```
{
    "source": { "file": { "path": "/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/file.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
    "columns": ["p1:String","p2:String","s:Integer"] } },
    "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "UPDATE lac2 set p='${input.p1}' UPSERT WHERE p='${input.p1}'"} }      
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/db",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "lac2", "extends": "V"},
                {"name": "isActingWith", "extends": "E"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**vertex_import_p2.json**

```
{
    "source": { "file": { "path": "/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/file.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
    "columns": ["p1:String","p2:String","s:Integer"] } },
    "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "UPDATE lac2 set p='${input.p2}' UPSERT WHERE p='${input.p2}'"} }      
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/db",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "lac2", "extends": "V"},
                {"name": "isActingWith", "extends": "E"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**edge_import_s.json**

```
{
    "source": { "file": { "path": "/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/file.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
    "columns": ["p1:String","p2:String","s:Integer"] } },
    "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "CREATE EDGE isActingWith FROM (SELECT FROM lac2 WHERE p='${input.p1}') TO (SELECT FROM lac2 WHERE p='${input.p2}') set score=${input.s}"} }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:/home/ivan/Cose/OrientDB/issues/stack/44641116/db",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "lac2", "extends": "V"},
                {"name": "isActingWith", "extends": "E"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here are the situation after the executions:

```
orientdb {db=db}> select from lac2

+----+-----+------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|p        |out_isActingWith   |in_isActingWith|
+----+-----+------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|0   |#21:6|lac2  |LGG_00001|[#25:5,#26:1,#27:1]|               |
|1   |#21:7|lac2  |LGG_01682|                   |[#25:5]        |
|2   |#22:3|lac2  |LGG_01831|                   |[#26:1]        |
|3   |#23:1|lac2  |LGG_01491|                   |[#27:1]        |
+----+-----+------+---------+-------------------+---------------+

4 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.003 sec(s).
orientdb {db=db}> select from isActingWith

+----+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS      |score|out  |in   |
+----+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|0   |#25:5|isActingWith|282  |#21:6|#21:7|
|1   |#26:1|isActingWith|183  |#21:6|#22:3|
|2   |#27:1|isActingWith|238  |#21:6|#23:1|
+----+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+

3 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.004 sec(s).
```

Comment: so you say If I wanna mesure the total execution time of the insertion , i just need to sum the total of the 3 right ?

Comment: hi, yea i think so

Comment: I am so grateful for your post. I tried for 4 hours to get a csv file to load (paring it down to very simple list of edges), reading all the ETL documentation very carefully, and still getting cryptic errors and getting really frustrated. I found that if my data doesn't fit their examples to a t, I'm out of luck.

Comment: @KrisP hope it helped in someway. faced the same problem

Comment: @IvanMainetti I'm seeing that it is taking too much time to load , is that normal ?

Comment: @IvanMainetti your code gives a really bad peformances and loads really slow for the entire file