# orientdb SEVER Error during extraction: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name is empty

Tags: graph, import, orientdb, vertices

I have this file that I'm trying to import on orientdb it has the following structure :

```
    p1  p2  combined_score
1   568703.LGG_00001    568703.LGG_01682    282
2   568703.LGG_00001    568703.LGG_01831    183
3   568703.LGG_00001    568703.LGG_01491    238
```

I'm doing the import using oetl :

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/Users/Desktop/files/file22/lac2.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "nodes" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {

       "dbURL": "plocal:/tmp/databases/db/db",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "nodes", "extends": "V"},


       ]
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to import the vertices first and then the nodes .
Yet I'm getting this error

```
2017-06-26 18:38:27:059 SEVER Error during extraction: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name is empty [OETLProcessor$OETLExtractorWorker]+ extracted 0 rows (0 rows/sec) - 0 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 2012ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 rows (0 rows/sec) - 0 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 3033ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 0 rows (0 rows/sec) - 0 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 4033ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

Nothing is loading ,How can I solve this ?

I'm using orientdb community-2.2.18 and tried 2.2.22 vrsion too and the problem is percisting

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx. Regards

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi    I'm using orientdb community-2.2.18

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I have tried to change the version , yet the problem is the same

Comment: AFAIU you CSV is tab separated;  please try to configure the separator: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Extractor.html#csv-extractor

Comment: @RobertoFranchini that first problem was solved, it was the first column in the header that starts incorrectly . now I get all the vertices are loaded yet there is nothing inserted in the database

Comment: @RobertoFranchini I'm wondering how do I specify that the p1, p2  attributes are the vertices

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what do you want to do with your data. AFAIU p1 should be mapped to a Vertex and p2 to another one. Am I right? but p1 and p2 are of the same class? Should you create an edge from p1 to p2? On naming: vertex are sometimes called nodes, while connections are edges. Could you update your question with the fix you made to the data and with more details on what you want to obtain? thax

Comment: @RobertoFranchini problem fixed on [post related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641116/orientdb-load-graph-csv-of-nodes-and-edges/44842099?noredirect=1#comment76666827_44842099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message:

```
2017-06-26 18:38:27:059 SEVER Error during extraction: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field name is empty
```

is because in your csv file, the name of the property in blank, you can modify your csv file in this way without giving it a name:

```
p1,p2,combined_score
1,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01682,282
2,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01831,183
3,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01491,238
```

and this will be your output:

```
+----+-----+------+----+----------------+----------------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|p1  |combined_score  |p2              |
+----+-----+------+----+----------------+----------------+
|0   |#17:0|nodes |1   |568703.LGG_01682|568703.LGG_00001|
|1   |#18:0|nodes |2   |568703.LGG_01831|568703.LGG_00001|
|2   |#19:0|nodes |3   |568703.LGG_01491|568703.LGG_00001|
+----+-----+------+----+----------------+----------------+
```

otherwise, if you wanna give it a name, do it in this way:

```
id,p1,p2,combined_score
1,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01682,282
2,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01831,183
3,568703.LGG_00001,568703.LGG_01491,238
```

and this will be the output:

```
+----+-----+------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|p1              |combined_score|p2              |id  |
+----+-----+------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----+
|0   |#17:0|nodes |568703.LGG_00001|282           |568703.LGG_01682|1   |
|1   |#18:0|nodes |568703.LGG_00001|183           |568703.LGG_01831|2   |
|2   |#19:0|nodes |568703.LGG_00001|238           |568703.LGG_01491|3   |
+----+-----+------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----+
```

I tried with 2.2.22.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I already fixed this as I mentionned in the comment above , But there is nothing inserted in the database. I guess it doesnt know which attributes are the vertices somehow , As I just need to specify the vertices for p1 and p2 and the score is gonna be representing the edge .do you have a clue of how to fix this

Comment: I already fixed this as I mentionned in the comment above , thank you