# Orientdb Import csv as a graph specify nodes from attributes

Tags: csv, graph, import, attributes, orientdb

I'm a newbie in Orientdb  and I have this csv file :

```
"id","p","p2","s"
"1","568703.LGG_00001","568703.LGG_01682",282
"2","568703.LGG_00001","568703.LGG_01831",183
"3","568703.LGG_00001","568703.LGG_01491",238
"4","568703.LGG_00001","568703.LRHM_1319",475
```

I'm trying to import it as a graph  with specifying the vertices to p1 ,and p2 attributes . and the edge is going to be created with the s field.
First I thought of creating the vertices and then proceed by the creation of the edges. but I can't find a clue of specifying the vetices from the attributes .

What I tried is :

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/Users/M/Desktop/files/file22/file.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {"separator": ","}},
  "transformers": [
    {
     "vertex": { "class": "nodes" } }

  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {

       "dbURL": "plocal:/tmp/databases/db/db1",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "nodes", "extends": "V"},


       ]


    }
  }
}
```

Nw Each row is inderted as a vertex and that is not what I want. What I need it the p1,p2 to be the vertices and the s should be a property of a vertex 
I guess there is some logic missing of the code.

**The schema : **

***p1————Has-Score———>p2***
(Has_score : having as a property the attribute s)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you add the database schema that you have in mind? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [orientdb load graph csv of nodes and edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641116/orientdb-load-graph-csv-of-nodes-and-edges)

Comment: @Ivan i have edited the question