# Orientdb Slow import large dataset how to make it faster?

Tags: performance, time, orientdb, bigdata

I'm working on a network of 17M edges and 20K vrtices , and I'm loading it into Orientdb using ETL tool but it is taking forever to load.

I tried the batch varying from 1000 to  100000 , yet still no change .

Is there an optimized way to make it load faster ? other tha using Java API
Any help would be appreciated.
I'm using 2.2.20 community version . 
Here is the ETL fo import :

```
{
    "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/Users/Muuna/Desktop/files/H.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
        "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
                "ignoreEmptyLines": true,
    "columns": ["id:Integer","p1:String","p2:String","s:Integer"] } },
    "transformers": [

        { "command": { "command": "UPDATE H set p='${input.p1}' UPSERT WHERE p='${input.p1}'"},"vertex": { "class": "H", "skipDuplicates": true} }      
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "PLOCAL:C:/orientdb/databases/Graph",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "H", "extends": "V"},
                {"name": "HAS_S", "extends": "E"}
            ],"indexes": [ {"class":"H", "fields":["p:String"], "type":"UNIQUE" }]
        }
    }
}
```

Based on [1]: [orientdb load graph csv of nodes and edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641116/orientdb-load-graph-csv-of-nodes-and-edges)
The same script is loaded twice to import the 2 vertices and another ETL for loading the edges .

```
Edges .
```

Based on [Ref][1]

```
{
    "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/Users/Muuna/Desktop/files/H.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {
        "separator": ",",
        "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
                "ignoreEmptyLines": true,
    "columns": ["id:Integer","p1:String","p2:String","s:Integer"] } },
    "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "CREATE EDGE HAS_S FROM (SELECT FROM H WHERE p='${input.p1}') TO (SELECT FROM H WHERE p='${input.p2}') set score=${input.s}"} }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "PLOCAL:C:/orientdb/databases/Graph",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "H", "extends": "V"},
                {"name": "HAS_S", "extends": "E"}
            ],"indexes": [ {"class":"H", "fields":["p:String"], "type":"UNIQUE" }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Can you post your ETL code?

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko I'm editing the question

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko Actually the creation of the edges that takes too long . I'm citing the script above